Bottomnavigationbar android:layout_height="wrap_content" problem
Merhabalar. Bottomnavigationbarın yüksekliğ xml dosyasında düzgün gözüküyor, fakat emulatorda resimde olduğu gibi yüksek gözüküüyor. Sorun gidermeme yardımcı olurmusunuz. Şimdiden teşekkür ediyorum.
enter image description here
android:layout_height'i, wrap_content yerine 30 -40dp yaptım. Bu seferde icon'lar gözükmüyor. Sınıf kısmından düzeltmeyi denedi, oradan da işe yaramadı.
